# FFT procedure for evaluationg a polynomial at $N$ Fourier points

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, recursive-algorithms

The following is the recursive FFT procedure of Algorithm for evaluationg a polynomial of length $N$ at $N$ Fourier points.

> Algorithm (FFT - fast Fourier transform).
>
> Input arguments.
>   $ \ \ $   integer $N=2^m$
>   $ \ \ $   polynomial
>   $\alpha (x)=\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}\alpha_i x^i$  $ \ \ $   primitive $N$th
>   root of unity $\omega$
>
> Ouput argument.
>   $ \ \ $   array $\textbf{A}=(A_0, \dots , A_{N-1})$
>   where $A_k=\alpha(\omega^k)$
>
> Auxiliary data.
>   $ \ \ $   integer $n=\frac{N}{2}$
>   $ \ \ $   polynomials $b(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}b_ix^i, c(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}c_ix^i$
>
> $ \ \ $   arrays $\textbf{B}=(B_0, \dots , B_{n-1}), \textbf{C}=(C_0,
> > \dots , C_{n-1})$
>
> procedure FFT($N, \alpha (x), \omega , \textbf{A}$);
>   $ \ \ $   if N=1
>   $ \ \ \ \ $       then
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $          {Basis.} $A_0
> > :=\alpha_0$
>   $ \ \ \ \ $       else
>   $ \ \ \ \ $       begin
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $           {Binary split.}
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $        $n:=\frac{N}{2};$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $         $b(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\alpha_{2i}x^i;$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $      $c(x):=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \alpha_{2i+1}x^i;$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $       {Recursive calls.}
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $           FFT($n, b(x),\omega^2, \textbf{B}$);
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $           FFT($n,c(x), \omega^2 , \textbf{C}$);
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $          {Combine.}
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $           for $k:=0$ until $n-1$ do
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $           begin
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $          $A_k:=B_k+\omega^k \times C_k;$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $          $A_{k+n}:=B_b-\omega^k \times C_k$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $end
>   end

I tried to implement the FFT algorithm at an example but I got stuck...

We have the polynmial $\alpha (x)=x^3+2x^2+5x+3$. ($N=2^2$)

> FFT($4, \alpha (x), \omega \textbf{A}$)
>   $ \ \ \ \ $ $n=2$
>   $ \ \ \ \ $ $b(x)=3+2x$
>   $ \ \ \ \ $ $c(x)=5+x$
>   $ \ \ \ \ $ FFT($2, b(x),\omega^2, \textbf{B}$)
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $n=1$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $b(x)=3$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $c(x)=2$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ FFT($1,b(x), \omega^2, \textbf{B}$)
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $B_0=3$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ FFT($1, c(x), \omega^2, \textbf{C}$)
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $C_0=2$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $k=0$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $B_0=B_0+\omega^0 \cdot C_0=5$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $B_2=B_0-\omega^0 \cdot C_0=1$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $k=1$
>   $ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $B_1=B_1+\omega^1 \cdot C_1$

Is it correct so far?